# Есть ли в Windows на уровне ОС какая-либо защита от переполнения буфера?

Tags: windows, c, безопасность, защита, c++

Добрый день!
У меня возникла проблема при реализации переполнения буфера.
Если я делаю прямо в программе так:

```
char buffer[4];
strcpy(buffer, "AAAA\xf9\xc0_и.т.д._мой_шеллкод_");
```

То шеллкод выполняется и все работает.
Если же я пишу в программе

```
char buffer[4];
strcpy(buffer, argv[1]);
```

И пытаюсь подать программе на вход шеллкод, то программа крашится.
Отсюда у меня возникли мысли, что возможно эту проблему как-то контролирует сама ОС? (Win 8.1)
Подскажите, так ли это? Если так, то возможно ли отключить этот контроль?

Comment: некоторые компиляторы могут вставлять так называемые canary words в стек - специальные случайные значения заносятся при вызове подпрограммы, когда подпрограмма завершила работу, эти "специальные значения" сравниваются с заведомо сохраненными.

Второй способ - это контроль страниц. Если в какой то части памяти будут храниться только данные, то кода там нет и выполнять код там нельзя и наоборот, если где то есть код, то изменять там значение другой частью кода обычно не нужно. Ещё со времен XP есть поддержка этой технологии ([not execute bit](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/NX_bit)).

Comment: @KoVadim, если я правильно понимаю ключик /GS, упомянутый VladD как раз отвечает за это? Он у меня отключен в настройках...

Comment: да, он canary words вставляет. Но если программа крашится, тогда запускайте отладчик и смотрите, где ругается. Писать шеллкод и не уметь пользоваться отладчиком - моветон.

Comment: @VladD, спасибо большое! Написала программку, которая вызывает мой buffer_overflow.exe и передает ей строку. И опять очень непонятный для меня результат... buffer_overflow.exe получает строку уже в правильном формате, но только первые 16 символов.... Остальное просто обрезается.... Случаем на аргумент argv нет никаких подобных ограничений?

Comment: @777Julia777: Хм. Нет, ограничений нету. То есть они есть, но там [порядка 32 килобайт](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2003/12/10/56028.aspx). Ищите, может, у вас где-то `\0` затесался?

Comment: @VladD, спасибо! Нашла методом тыка символ, который ему не нравится и который он не хочет передавать в аргумент - 0х20, символ пробела. И соответственно он считает остаток строки уже вторым аргументом, а не первым...

Comment: @777Julia777: Угу. Здесь уже фича парсера командной строки самой программы (то есть, рантайм-библиотеки), которая делит большую комстроку на отдельные аргументы. Это, наверное, можно обойти заключив строку в кавычки. Но не уверен, не попадут ли кавычки в строку.

Comment: @VladD, с кавычками все равно обрубает(

Comment: @777Julia777: Ну, если не получается, попробуйте переделать шеллкод так, чтобы он не содержал символа 0x20. Вы пытаетесь взломать систему, вы же не ожидаете, что всё будет просто?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Такими вещами занимается пара из ОС и компилятора.

Например, Visual Studio содержит [ключ `/GS`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8dbf701c%28v=vs.120%29.aspx) (по умолчанию включён), который активизирует т. н. stack canary: в определённые места в стеке записывается случайное число, и если впоследствии это число оказывается затёрто, детектируется stack smash.

Чтобы отключить, попробуйте ключ `/GS-`.

Кроме того, в отладочном режиме Visual Studio вставляет дополнительные проверки границ массивов, так что вам, возможно, придётся переключиться в Release Mode (или поискать, как это отключается в свойствах проекта).

---

По поводу разницы в поведении Release и Debug Mode.

Для начала: выход за границу выделенной памяти есть undefined behaviour. Убедитесь, что вы в курсе этого понятия, оно отвечает за 95% проблем в безопасности; вы, как будущий специалист по software security, должны это особенно отчётливо понимать. Undefined behaviour значит, что компилятор не имеет никаких обязательств в этой ситуации, и **любое** поведение программы правильно.

Теперь, в случае отладочного режима, компилятор специально для разработчиков вставляет проверки на затирание памяти для того, чтобы сообщить об ошибке как только она случится (иначе найти проблему будет сложнее). Такой контроль не требуется по стандарту, и разумеется отнимает время пробега программы. В случае release-режима, такие проверки не вставляются для ускорения работы программы, и вся безопасность держится на stack canaries, ASLR, NX-битах и тому подобных менее надёжных вещах. Которые тоже, строго говоря, не требуются стандартом, и вставляются исключительно по доброй воле разработчиков компилятора (и к тому же отключаются соответствующими ключами).

Comment: @VladD, скомпилировала в релизе и получаю очень удивительный для меня результат.
Код
char buffer[4];
strcpy(buffer, argv[1]);
printf(buffer);
Выполняется всегда вне зависимости от длинны входных данных. Хоть 100 символов на вход подавай, он все равно их печатает...

Comment: @777Julia777: ну да, вы затёрли чужие данные в стеке, что ж удивительного? Это C++, memory safety отсутствует.

Comment: @VladD, не могу понять... Почему тогда в дебаге ошибка есть, а в релизе нет? Ведь если программа выполняется без ошибки, то должен затираться адрес возврата и выполняться шеллкод...

Comment: потому что дебаг и релиз версия могут очень сильно отличаться. К примеру, в релизе компилятор может заинлайнить функцию или даже выбросить кусок кода, который ничего не делает. На этом попалились многие "разработчики крутейших защитных систем для кода на базе запутывания кода".

Comment: @VladD, @KoVadim, прочитала, поняла, спасибо! Возник еще вопрос. Когда я в программе пишу "AAAAAAAA\xf9\xc0...", он сам понимает эти значения не как символы, а как опкоды. А когда я пишу такое в командной строке типа "buffer_overflow.exe  AAAAAAAA\xf9\xc0...... ", разве не будут они восприниматься просто как символы? С cmd-шки они будут правильно преобразовываться?

@VladD, а почему Вы решили, что я будущий специалист по безопасности?

Comment: @777Julia777: Ну, задания по написанию и встраиванию шеллкода — типичный набор знаний пен-тестера.

Comment: @VladD, да, Вы угадали, как раз учусь этим заниматься :)

А подскажите, пожалуйста, не может быть проблемы с кодировкой или с чем нибудь подобным при записи в argv?
Я заметила, что у меня если отобразить строку, созданную в программе(типа \xf9\xc0...), то она печатается как набор ANSI-символов (что как я понимаю и должно быть). А если передать строку в качестве параметра argv и вывести на экран, то печатаются тупо те же символы "\xf9\xc0..."...

Comment: @777Julia777: Ну, с этим-то понятно. Вы печатаете `\xf...`, кто ж их будет интерпретировать как escape-последовательность? При компиляции этим занимается компилятор, потому что так описано в стандарте языка. А если вы запускаете программу, то для командного интерпретатора Windows (в отличие от bash, например) бэкслеш не имеет никакого особого значения, вот оно и передаётся «как есть».

Если вы хотите легко и точно управлять комстрокой, может быть, стоит написать другую программу для запуска этой? Там вы сможете сконструировать комстроку как захотите.