# Какое влияние на приложение оказывает проверка безопасности (\GS)?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio

**Дано:** сетевое приложение, в процессе обмена сетевыми пакетами ошибка может возникнуть где угодно (сбой, неверный ответ от сервера и т.д.).

**Пояснение:** Переодически выбивало в разных местах кода исключение о переполнении стека или нарушение прав доступа при чтении по адресу..., причем блоки `try\catch` не помогали. В опциях студии по умолчанию была включена `проверка безопасности (\GS)`, отключил ее и приложение начало работать стабильно (по крайней мере на первый взгляд).

**Вопрос:** какими последствиями черевато отключение `проверки безопасности (\GS)` кроме риска взлома приложения?

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/401929/10105

Comment: А try/catch и не должен помогать. Срыв стека есть фатальная ошибка, нужно честно закрешить приложение и выписать программистам _внушение_.

Comment: @VladD, скорее уже не программистам, а серверам, которые гадят в протокол...

Comment: Программа не имеет права доверять данным, пришедшим из сети. Никогда. Если протокол говорит, что придёт 1 байт, а сервер присылает 3, а программист не проверил, и выделил только один — виноват программист. Программа должна не упасть, а сообщить в лог о нарушении протокола.

Comment: @VladD, спецификация - есть спецификация, а логирование пакетов от "кривых" серверов - не есть хорошо, логирование создает дополнительную нагрузку, а в многопоточной реализации - эта нагрузка становится очень существенной.

Comment: Окей, значит, не логировать, а немедленно дропать соединение. Но факт остаётся фактом: убрать проверку для «оптимизации» — преступление. Доверять данным из сети просто нельзя.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ключ Visual Studio `/GS` [защищает от переполнения буфера](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8dbf701c%28v=vs.120%29.aspx) в стеке. Если отключение этого ключа приводит к изменению поведения программы, значит, в программе собственно и присутствует срыв стека и запись по адресу «на кого бог пошлёт».

Переполнение буфера есть undefined behaviour, следовательно, случиться может *что угодно*. Не пытайтесь заткнуть сообщение об ошибке, код проекта серьёзно болен, нужно исправлять баги.

Comment: @Alexis: Проблема undefined behaviour в том, что последствия реально **не определены**. То есть, если крешнется в другом месте, это ещё хорошо. А имеет право например не выполнить какую-нибудь операцию молча, или скипнуть проверку. То есть имеет право на любую ошибку. В этом и есть суть UB: объём нанесённого вреда не ограничен и не локализуем.

Comment: @Alexis: Вы пришли на небезопасный язык. С ним всё намного хуже.

Comment: Благодарю, теперь примерно понятны возможные последствия. Необходимо править код (.

Comment: @Alexis: Вот мои любимые ссылки насчёт UB: [(1)](http://blog.llvm.org/2011/05/what-every-c-programmer-should-know.html), [(2)](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20140627-00/?p=633/). Обязательно почитайте, чтобы почувствовать серьёзность проблемы.